# KERAS selects same fraction from each class for validation (for eg. Validation fraction = 0.2)

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

i have been reading many forums, no clear answer. At many places they say, that it selects the last 20% for our example from the data. Say our data in in two folders Cats and Dogs... so if it were to select only last 20% of the data from Dogs folder and none from cats, wont it be wrong ? . Can keras actually make such a blunder in this code. can you please reassure that the data being selected by keras for validation has same fraction of images from each class.

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split=0.2)
print("Preparing training dataset...")
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    training_folder_name,
    target_size=pretrained_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='training') # set as training data

print("Preparing validation dataset...")
validation_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    training_folder_name,
    target_size=pretrained_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='validation') # set as validation data
```

Output:
Preparing training dataset...
Found 3357 images belonging to 3 classes.
Preparing validation dataset...
Found 838 images belonging to 3 classes.

These 838 images have equal fraction from each class ?

Answer (score 0):

Does the validation set have to include cats and dogs, if classifying cats and dogs? Yes.
What the validation set actually includes depends on how you implement the program, it is not a responsibility of Keras.

Comment: updated the question... with the code. does it quarantee that fractions are equal from each class ?